# Question on Gagliardo-Nirenberg.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

On page 679 of [this paper](https://www.i2m.univ-amu.fr/perso/thierry.gallouet/art.d/brezisgallouet.pdf), the authors claim they can get a special case of Gagliardo-Nirenberg with a constant of 1/2. They prove this using functions in $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$, for which the proof in the footnote is clear. I have no idea how they can extend this to functions in $H^1(\Omega)$ without picking up a constant from an extension operator. If you have the time, this small part is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

They don't deal with functions in $H^1(\Omega)$. Recall that $u$ vanishes on the boundary of $\Omega$ (conditions (1)). Since the boundary is smooth, this means $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$. Therefore, the *zero extension* of $u$ to $\mathbb R^n$ is an $H^1$ function. The extension by zero does not increase the $H^1$ norm.

Since a   compactly supported $H^1$ function can be approximated in $H^1$ norm by compactly supported $C^\infty $ functions, the inequality follows.

Comment: This is good. You still do need that  $H^1_0 \subset L^4$ continuously though, right? Because in your $H^1$ approximation you need convergence of their $L^4$ norms.

Comment: @A.AdamAzzam When arguing by density of smooth functions, you only need to check that the right hand side (the bigger one) is continuous in the norm. Think of the inequality as the statement that we have a Lipschitz map into $L^4$. If we have a Lipschitz map on a dense subset, it automatically extends to the whole space.

Comment: @A.AdamAzzam In any case, we are on two dimensions, so Sobolev embedding gives $L^p$ for all finite $p$.